# Creating checkbox inside elements in a row

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, checkbox

This is my function buildrow which is creating row inside the table, Inside it I am trying to create checkbox item for every  column but I am just getting the text instead of column. How can I fix it. Basically I want checkbox inside every column in the created row

```js
function buildrow(){
    
    var table = document.getElementById("data");
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var l;
    var m;
    for (l = 0; l < id1.length; l++) {
        
        for(m=0; m < plans["data"].length; m++){
            if(plans["data"][m]["ID"]!==null){
            if(id1[l]==plans["data"][m]["ID"]){
            firstcol ='input type="checkbox" class="checks"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="checkbox" onchange="myFunction(event)"';
            
                var table = document.getElementById("data");
                var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
                cell1.innerHTML=firstcol;
            }
            }
    
            }
    }
    }
```

```css
tr:nth-child(2){
                background-color: #003a6a !important;
                border-top: none;
                height:30px
            }
```

Comment: Hi, You have not written the proper syntax for checkbox, update the line `'input type="checkbox" class="checks"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="checkbox" onchange="myFunction(event)"'` to `'<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="checkbox" onchange="myFunction(event)" />'`

Comment: If this does not help, then can you please add the HTML code you have tried.

Comment: Yes it helps I have one more question any css change I am applying on it is not getting updated

Comment: Can share some code, so that it will be easier to help.

Comment: yes i have updated the css part, basically i am trying to style this second row where i have input checkboxes

Comment: I'm seeing a *lot* of questions over the last few days that start `document.getElementById("data");` and are questions about adding things to tables - are these from an (online?) course?     Not a problem as homework questions are [on-topic] (as long as asked as questions, not "do it for me").  Just curious

Comment: So, the css is applied to a single row, or it's not being even applied.

Comment: only the background-color is being applied to the 2nd row as i have mentioned

Comment: @freedomn-m..learning frontend dev and creating our own project and ask questions wherever we stuck

Comment: It works completely fine for me, all the three styles get applied.

Comment: Not working for me, I have applied css to all `<tr>` aswell, can that be the issue, its not overwriting?